# Error on Validation Message databind

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am working in big application, having too many view models. I want to display my message in custom location. I have find these tutorials online

http://jsfiddle.net/internetH3ro/tLN7r/

http://jsfiddle.net/Y85Kh/ .

When i tried to implement i am getting the error
"VMData is not defined" then I thought of calling it from the view model(viewmodel.VMData) .there I was getting the error "Message: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined". Is there I am missing something or I need add anything extra to make it accessible while using different view models.

```
var data = {
    Name: 'test'
};

ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messageTemplate: null
});
```

**Added** : http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/1/

Comment: can you show your code or make fiddle?

Comment: Added http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/1/ .Please look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw your code, you can not use validationMessage any where other then under foreach loop it must be in in tbody.
In configuration make insertMessages false.

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> <span data-bind="validationMessage: Type"></span>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/2/)

Comment: is it same for the viewmodel errors, because i am using knockout validations and my error count always return as zero.

Comment: @Hsakarp see updated fiddle. [http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/5/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49546/discussion-between-hsakarp-and-akhlesh)